# Firefox hover seems to ignore visited

Tags: css, firefox, hover, visited

When I use the hover and visited properties on a styled component it seems to conflict.

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-volhard-n03ik?file=/src/styles.css:0-326

```
.button:visited {
  background-color: green;
}

.button:visited:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

What I am trying to archive here is having 2 states:

- not visited: black hover directly to blue
- visited: green hover directly to red

But in Firefox it seems to ignore the visited state on hover and go from green to blue to red. (In chrome it seems to work perfectly)

Does anyone has experience with this and know how to fix it?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I added the css of it to the thread and adjusted the title.